# Java Socket mixing previous messages recent posts

Tags: java, sockets, chat, datagram

Hello I am doing a chat with java using internal IP network but I have a error after sending some messages the program this mixing previous messages with the newly sent and can not find the why of it.
follows the code.

Conexao.java

public class Conexao extends Observable {

```
private String ip;
private int porta;
private String mensagem;

public Conexao(String ip, int porta) {
    this.ip = ip;
    this.porta = porta;
    new Thread(new Recebe()).start();
}

public String getMensagem() {
    return mensagem;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public int getPorta() {
    return porta;
}

public void envia(String texto) {
    new Thread(new Envia(texto)).start();     
}

public void notifica(String mensagem) {
    this.mensagem = mensagem;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

class Recebe implements Runnable {

    byte[] dadosReceber = new byte[65508];
    boolean erro = false;
    DatagramSocket socket = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = new DatagramSocket(getPorta());
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            erro = false;
            while (!erro) {
                DatagramPacket pacoteRecebido = new DatagramPacket(dadosReceber, dadosReceber.length);
                try {

                    socket.receive(pacoteRecebido);
                    socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                    byte[] b = pacoteRecebido.getData();
                    String s = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                        if (b[i] != 0) {
                            s += (char) b[i];
                        }
                    }

                    String nome = pacoteRecebido.getAddress().toString() + " disse:";
                    notifica(nome + s);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("erro");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    erro = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class Envia implements Runnable {

    String texto;

    public Envia(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        byte[] dados = texto.getBytes();

        try {
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(getIp());               
            DatagramPacket pacote = new DatagramPacket(dados, dados.length, addr, getPorta());
            clientSocket.send(pacote);
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

JanelaChat.java

public class JanelaChat extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Observer {

```
private Conexao conexao;

public JanelaChat(Conexao conexao) {
    super("chat");
    this.conexao = conexao;
    initComponents();
    conexao.addObserver(this);
    escreve("Chat iniciado com " + conexao.getIp() + ":" + conexao.getPorta());
    mensagemjTextArea.requestFocusInWindow();
}

private void envia() {
    if (!mensagemjTextArea.getText().isEmpty()) {
        conexao.envia(mensagemjTextArea.getText());
        escreve("Você disse: " + mensagemjTextArea.getText());
        mensagemjTextArea.setText("");
    }
}

private void escreve(String texto) {
    chatjTextArea.append(texto + "\n");
    if (!chatjTextArea.getText().isEmpty() && !chatjTextArea.isFocusOwner()) {
        chatjTextArea.setCaretPosition(chatjTextArea.getText().length() - 1);
    }

}
```

Thank you for your attention and sorry for my english I hope I have been clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're making untenable assumptions about your transport. UDP datagrams can be delivered multiple times, out of order, or not at all. If you want reliability, sequencing, non-repetition, etc., use TCP.

You have other problems. The correct way to construct a String from a newly received datagram (assuming it only contains character data) is:

```
String s = new String(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());
```

You don't need all the null-checking: just the above.